# What is the name of the drum type that sounds like a tin can?

Tags: rock, drums

It sounds like drumming with a stick over a simple tin can turned upside down.

I have noticed it many times, but in particularly in a couple of songs featuring Slash:

- [Night Train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qyf8oRF6Trg) from 0:07 to 0:28
- [30 Years to Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4ySsES7hyA) from 3:03 to 3:14

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like a cowbell to me. The "Cowbells in popular music" section of the "[Cowbell (instrument)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowbell_(instrument))" Wikipedia page notes that *Guns N' Roses have often used the cowbell, notably in "Nightrain," "Welcome to the Jungle," and "It's So Easy."*

Comment: Yeah, I had this recollection of often hearing this one in several of their songs, but I wasn't really sure of that except for Night Train. Now I've recently heard the same sound in one of Slash's more recent albums, and I immediately "sensed his touch" with that sound (didn't want to name it "Slash Drum" in this question because I wasn't sure who was "responsible" for it in they days of GNR). Thanks!!!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCd0OjjCz88